# Pass positional arguments

Tags: bash, shell-script, xargs

I'm pretty new to xargs

I have a command

```
kubectl taint nodes xx.xx.xx.xx dedicated=test:NoSchedule --overwrite=true
```

I have my command , how do i pass the positional values to xargs? they are not getting passed.

```
echo \$NODES \$key_and_value \$overwrite \$label  |
  xargs -I -l % sh -c 'kubectl taint nodes  \$0 % \$1 --overwrite=\$2'
```

basically i'm doing something like this, i'm getting those values from the jenkins ui
The values are dynamic

```
echo \$NODES \$key_and_value \$overwrite  |
  xargs -I% bash -c 'kubectl --kubeconfig ./kube-configs/config \
  taint nodes % "\$0"  "\$1" --overwrite=% "\$2"'`
```

error :

```
16:06:42 Error: invalid argument "ip-xx-xx-xx-xx.ec2.internal" for "--overwrite" flag: strconv.ParseBool: parsing "ip-xx-xx-xx-xx.ec2.internal": invalid syntax
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include an example of what you're trying to do?  Given your example, I don't understand why you need `xargs` at all.  Can't you just run `kubectl tain $NODES $key_and_value --overwrite $label`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define your positional arguments outside the command string:

```
 echo a b c d  | xargs -I VALUES sh -c "echo \$4 \$3 \$2 \$1" command VALUES
```

This is not well described (in my case from `man dash` )

> -c
>
> Read commands from the command_string operand instead of from the standard input.  Special parameter 0 will be set from the command_name operand and the positional parameters ($1, $2, etc.)  set from the **remaining argument operands**.

But behaves like better explained in `man bash`:

> -c
>
> If the -c option is present, then commands are read from the first non-option argument command_string.  If there are **arguments after the command_string**, the first argument is assigned to $0 and any remaining arguments **are assigned to the positional parameters**.  The assignment to $0 sets the name of the shell, which is used in warning and error messages.

*Note that the command_string is set as first argument after the command string in quotes (=`$0`)*

In your case, you used the `-I` option without argument which means that the values `xargs` reads are not just appended but need to be called via `'{}'`. So either use this:

```
 echo 1 2 3 4 | xargs sh -c "echo \$4 \$3 \$2 \$1" command
```

OR this

```
 echo 1 2 3 4 | xargs -I sh -c "echo \$4 \$3 \$2 \$1" command '{}'
```

---

Hint: use the `-x` option from `sh` and the `-t` option from `xargs` to better track odd behavior. They will print each command line before executing it.